# Querying indexes in mongoid

Tags: mongoid

Just wondering, if I index a field in mongoid is there a special query form I should be using to speed up queries using that index or does Class.where(index: value) utilize that automatically?

Answer (score 1):

I quote the creator of the Mongoid ODM from the following bug report in GitHub https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/1276

> If you have fields that are indexed then it's determined on the
>   database side if the index is to be used - there's nothing special on
>   the Mongoid side of things when using criteria to provide index hints.
>   Please remember though if you created the index in Mongoid to run rake
>   db:create_indexes to ensure it actually got created in the db.